# Why use __attribute__((weak)) and #pragma weak?

Tags: c

I am reading code to define the interrupt vector for an STM32 [here](http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/cortex-m3-interrupt-vector-table/). For some reason, both `__attribute__((weak))` and `#pragma weak` are used:

```
void __attribute__((weak)) NMI_Handler(void); /* NMI Handler */ // [line 12]
#pragma weak NMI_Handler = Default_Handler    /* NMI handler */ // [line 48]
```

Somehow it feels that using both `__attribute__((weak))` and `#pragma weak` is redundant.

Can we do without one of them? Is this style standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right but...

```
#pragma weak NMI_Handler = Default_Handler
```

alone can accomplish what is intended. ***But it would be good to add `__attribute__((weak))` to the function prototypes*** for the following reason -

Assume that the file is a huge one with definitions and prototypes spilled all over the file. Now you use an IDE/Editor to jump to the prototype of `NMI_Handler` and when you arrive there and don't see `__attribute__((weak))` attached to `NMI_Handler` you might as well assume that `NMI_Handler` is defined somewhere else and go on a goose hunt and end up nowhere! Now, as they've explicitly added `__attribute__((weak))`, you get an idea that this function's definition *might not be there* and you can now search for any pragma aliasing instead of trying to find the actual definition of the function which doesn't/may not exist!